# Python threading.Timer objects not triggering after multi-hour timer

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, bots, irc

I'm writing a small IRC bot which uses data grabbed from a JSON API. It's a list of events, which contains at the front any running event, followed by any future events.

I'd like to alert the channel twice before each event: an hour prior, and five minutes prior. To do this I'm attempting to create threading.Timer events which trigger at the appropriate time. I chose this method because the IRC bot requires running in an infinite loop, so the alerts need to run in their own thread. I've several times had the first alert work, but only if it triggers within ~5 minutes of the bot starting. If I start it say, 8 hours before the next event, it won't trigger the method at all. Here's the alert code: I've cut out the portions of the code which parse the time from the API, since that is already working and is just clutter for purposes of this question.

```
USE = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
ZULU=pytz.timezone('Zulu')
NET = 0
r = requests.get('http://api.pathofexile.com/leagues?type=event')
events=r.json()
NextEvent=events[0];
now = datetime.datetime.now(USE)
nextEventTime = events[0]['startAt']
/\/\
timeConverted=datetime.datetime(eventTimeY, eventTimeM, eventTimeD, eventTimeH, eventTimeMin, 0, 0).replace(tzinfo=ZULU)
until = timeConverted - now
NET = until.total_seconds()

#Race Alerts

def hourAlert():
   r = requests.get('http://api.pathofexile.com/leagues?type=event')
   events=r.json()
   NextEvent=events[0];
   now = datetime.datetime.now(USE)
   nextEventTime = events[0]['startAt']
   \/\/
   timeConverted=datetime.datetime(eventTimeY, eventTimeM, eventTimeD, eventTimeH, eventTimeMin, 0, 0).replace(tzinfo=ZULU)   
   until = timeConverted - now
   NET = until.total_seconds()
   print("HOURALERT")
   if until.total_seconds() > 0:
    irc.send(bytes('PRIVMSG '+channel+' '+"EVENT ALERT - 1 HOUR - "+NextEvent['id'] +' - Occurs at '+NextEvent['startAt']+' - '+NextEvent['url']+'\r\n', 'UTF-8')) #gives event info
    print("Starting Timer to event - "+str(NET-300))
    sAlert = threading.Timer(NET-300, startAlert)
    sAlert.start()
   else:
    NextEvent=events[1];
    now = datetime.datetime.now(USE)
    nextEventTime = events[1]['startAt']
    \/\/
    timeConverted=datetime.datetime(eventTimeY, eventTimeM, eventTimeD, eventTimeH, eventTimeMin, 0, 0).replace(tzinfo=ZULU)    
    until = timeConverted - now
    NET = until.total_seconds()
    irc.send(bytes('PRIVMSG '+channel+' '+"EVENT ALERT - 1 HOUR - "+NextEvent['id'] +' - Occurs at '+NextEvent['startAt']+' - '+NextEvent['url']+'\r\n', 'UTF-8')) #gives event info
    print("Starting Timer to next event - "+str(NET-300))
    sAlert = threading.Timer(NET-300, startAlert)
    sAlert.start()  
def startAlert():
   r = requests.get('http://api.pathofexile.com/leagues?type=event')
   events=r.json()
   NextEvent=events[0];
   now = datetime.datetime.now(USE)
   nextEventTime = events[1]['startAt']
   \/\/
   timeConverted=datetime.datetime(eventTimeY, eventTimeM, eventTimeD, eventTimeH, eventTimeMin, 0, 0).replace(tzinfo=ZULU)
   until = timeConverted - now
   NET = until.total_seconds()
   print("STARTALERT")
   irc.send(bytes('PRIVMSG '+channel+' '+"EVENT ALERT - STARTING IN 5 MINUTES - "+NextEvent['id'] +' - '+NextEvent['url']+'\r\n', 'UTF-8')) #gives event info
   NextEvent=events[1];
   if until.total_seconds() > 3600:
    print("Starting Timer to 1hr - " + str(NET-3600))
    hAlert = threading.Timer(NET-3600, hourAlert)
    hAlert.start()
   else:
    print("Starting Timer to event - " +str(NET-300))
    sAlert = threading.Timer(NET-300, startAlert)
    sAlert.start()
if until.total_seconds() > 3600:
  print("Starting Timer to 1hr - " + str(NET-3600))
  hAlert = threading.Timer(NET-3600, hourAlert)
  hAlert.start()
elif until.total_seconds() > 300:
  print("Starting Timer to event - " + str(NET-300))
  hAlert = threading.Timer(NET-300, startAlert)
  hAlert.start() 
else:
  NextEvent=events[1];
  now = datetime.datetime.now(USE)
  nextEventTime = events[1]['startAt']
  \/\/
  timeConverted=datetime.datetime(eventTimeY, eventTimeM, eventTimeD, eventTimeH, eventTimeMin, 0, 0).replace(tzinfo=ZULU)
  until = timeConverted - now
  NET = until.total_seconds()
  print("Starting Timer to next event 1h - "+str(NET-3600))
  hAlert = threading.Timer(NET-3600, hourAlert)
  hAlert.start()
#End Alerts
```

I suspected for a time that my issue was using the timedelta.seconds value instead of total_seconds(), but I wont know if that works for a few hours yet. The main reason I'm asking here is because this code works in a testbed: if I tell it that the next event is in 30 seconds, and to trigger 15 and 5 before the event, it works just fine. However, when I bring the code back to multi-hour timespans, the events often won't trigger. They don't error out, they just straight don't work: not even the alert prints happen.

Thanks for any help you guys might be!

edit: I should mention, this is the first python program that I've written, but I'm a fairly experienced coder overall. My problem might be language related in that I'm doing something in a way python doesn't want me to. I'm unsure, for example, if nesting events like this would cause them to never trigger, because each is waiting for the full resolution of the child's function before triggering its own.

edit2: After more work, I can get the first alert to work, but despite creating the next Timer according to print statements, it never triggers. Is something with the nesting of triggers wrong?

Comment: It's a bit late, but in case you don't know about it, python has a [great event scheduling module in the stdlib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html)

Comment: I saw it, but even the page you linked advises threading.Timer if you dont want to hold up the main thread waiting. Thanks for the input though!